# React Native Can't nest View Inside Text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, view, native

```
<View>
<Text>
{/* Adding notification if exists otherwise ignore */}
{post.hasNotification ? post.notifications: ''}
</Text>
</View>
```

How could I wrap a View component around post.notifications? When I do this I get an error Nesting View withing Text is not currently supported. I need to wrap it with a View component so I can style it.

Comment: could you share your code?

Comment: I shared above, or maybe my question is explained poorly?

Comment: {post.hasNotification ? <View>post.notifications</View>: ' ' }
Is my desired code, with view component wrapping post.notifications

Comment: you can't use <View> inside <Text> component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use View component inside Text component. Try this,

```
<View>
     {post.hasNotification ? <View><Text>post.notifications</Text></View> : ' '}
 </View>
```

Comment: Changing ' ' to null seemed to fix it using your code, thank you.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/07/06/version-0.63#other-notable-improvements Since RN 0.63 it is now possible to have a `View` component inside a `Text`