# Add icon near last words of text (truncated or not) not showing for android

Tags: android, react-native

This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

and it's working for iOS but Android refuses to display the icon for truncated text:

[image]

Code:

```
 const Title = styled.Text`
  color: ${colorPalette.N80};
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16.8px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  ${() => ({ ...fontFamilyForStyledComponents(typeStyles.alternative.bold) })};
`;


const DescriptionWrapper = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
`;

const TextWrapper = styled.Text`
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

const Description = styled.Text`
  color: ${colorPalette.B1100};
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19.6px;
  ${() => ({ ...fontFamilyForStyledComponents(typeStyles.regular.regular) })};
`;

const PremiumIcon = styled.View`
  width: 9px;
  height: 14px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: ${isAndroid ? 0 : 2}px;
`;



  // ....

  const [truncatedTitle, setTruncatedTitle] = useState('');

  const isTruncated = (lines) => {
    const numberOfLines = lines.length;
    if (lines.length < 3)
      return false;
    if (isAndroid && lines.length>3) { return true}
    // lines.length equals to numberOfLines on iOS if text is truncated or it
    // takes exactly numberOfLines
    // This is used to trim some chars from the last line chars to display the lock at the end of the 3 dots 
    return lines[numberOfLines-1].text.length > lines[0].text.length-5
  }

  const onTextLayout = (event: any) => {
    const { lines } = event.nativeEvent;

    // If the text is truncated we make sure there is space for the lock icon at the end of the 
    // string by removing about 10% of last row characters if last row is too big.
    if (!truncatedTitle && isTruncated(lines)) {
      let text = lines.slice(0, 3).map((line: any) => line.text).join('');
      const lineLength = Math.max(lines[0].text.length, lines[1].text.length)
      setTruncatedTitle(text.substr(0, Math.floor(2.8*lineLength)).concat('...'));
    }
  }

   
 // ...
 return (
  <TextWrapper hasIcon={hasIcon} numberOfLines={3} ellipsizeMode='tail' 
      onTextLayout={onTextLayout} >
            <Description>
              {truncatedTitle || title}
            </Description>
            <Text>
              <Spacer />
              {!item.props.isPremium && (
                <PremiumIcon>
                  <NewsFeedPremiumIcon /> // <-- this is a simple svg icon
                </PremiumIcon>
              )}
            </Text>
  </TextWrapper>
 )
```

Any workaround/solution including using a react native library to add the icon at the end of the last word of text will be tested and accepted if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be that your wrapping a View component in a Text component, which is not allowed.  Likely iOS is just more tolerant of it.  Try to rearrange the elements so that any Text is within a View, but not vise-versa.

See related discussion here: [React Native Can't nest View Inside Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237424/react-native-cant-nest-view-inside-text)

Comment: Newer versions of RN support View inside Text https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/07/06/version-0.63#other-notable-improvements

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I wasn't aware.  However, I should add that I've continued to see various issues with nesting of `Text` elements even in recent versions of RN.  (For example, since `Text`'s are usually collapse, some style props (like `opacity`) cannot be set from the inner ones. )  So I wouldn't assume this isn't related.  Have you tried it without the `View` nesting?

Answer (score 0):

As workaround for this I had to add a `View` (with the icon aligned bottom) next to the text component for the case when text is truncated.

Attention:

1. below code handles only the case of `maxNumberOfLines=3`, to have the code work you will have to add an extra parameter to the below component.
2. the returned tree might be simplified and remove some of the extra wrappers.

```
    const Spacer = styled.View`
      width: ${relativeSize('small')};
    `;
    
    const ContentWrapper = styled.View`
      width: 87%;
      padding-vertical: 10px;
    `;
    
    const Title = styled.Text`
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 17px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    `;
    
       
    const DescriptionWrapper = styled.View`
      width: 98%;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
    `;
    
    const TextWrapper = styled.Text<{isTruncated: boolean }>`
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: ${props =>
       props.isTruncated ? '96%' : '98%'};
    `;
    
    const Description = styled.Text`
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 19px;
    `;
    
    const PremiumIcon = styled.View`
      width: 16px;
      height: 14px;
      padding-right: 4px;
      padding-left: ${isAndroid ? 0 : 4}px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      padding-bottom: ${isAndroid ? 0 : 2}px;
    `;
    
    // This is used as container only for the case of truncated text
    const PremiumIconWrapper = styled.View`
      height: 55px;
      width: 20px;
      padding-right: 4px;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      padding-bottom: 2px;
    `;
    
    export default (props) => {
      const { item } = props;
      const { title } = item.props;
    
      const [isTitleTruncated, setIsTitleTruncated] = useState(false);
    
      const computeIsTextTruncated = (lines: Array<{ text: string }>) => {
        const numberOfLines = lines.length;
        if (lines.length < 3) return false;
        if (isAndroid && lines.length > 3) {
          return true;
        }
        // in IOS lines.length is number of lines if text is truncated or it
        // takes exactly max number of allowed lines
        return (
          lines[numberOfLines - 1].text.length >
          Math.max(lines[0].text.length, lines[1].text.length)
        );
      };
    
      const onTextLayout = (event: any) => {
        const { lines } = event.nativeEvent;
    
        // If the text is truncated we position the icon after the 3 dots in a different way
        // This approach was done due to an Android bug related to visibility of this icon
        if (!isTitleTruncated && computeIsTextTruncated(lines)) {
          setIsTitleTruncated(true);
        }
      };
    
      return (
          <ContentWrapper>
            <Title>{newsTeamNameFormatted}</Title>
            <DescriptionWrapper>
              <TextWrapper
                isTruncated={isTitleTruncated}
                numberOfLines={3}
                ellipsizeMode="tail"
                onTextLayout={onTextLayout}
              >
                <Description>{title}</Description>
                <Text>
                  <Spacer />
                  {!isTitleTruncated && (
                    <PremiumIcon>
                      <NewsFeedPremiumIcon />
                    </PremiumIcon>
                  )}
                </Text>
              </TextWrapper>
              {isTitleTruncated && (
                <PremiumIconWrapper>
                  <PremiumIcon>
                    <NewsFeedPremiumIcon />
                  </PremiumIcon>
                </PremiumIconWrapper>
              )}
            </DescriptionWrapper>
          </ContentWrapper>
      );
    };
```